# How do i make a program where i can close and reopen it and it keeps the data?

Tags: memory

EXAMPLE: the entire program is a textbox and not a single line of code (besides the answer to my question) the text box is blang and i type "something". i close the program and reopen it and "something" will still be in the textbox. hopefully that makes it clearer

Comment: You need to store it somewhere, not enough information about your environment to really help

Comment: You can't have an "entire program" with a textbox and "not a single line of code" with content storage. Your question makes no sense. Even if you were able to "store the content in memory", you'd still have to have code to retrieve it and put it back into the textbox. Once you close your app, the memory it owns is released, and can be used by another application.

Comment: He wants to know how to save the state of the program. But yes the question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

For a vague question I give a vague answer:

Save the contents of the textile to disk. Then when program loads, set the text to the data stored on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Log the values of the Textbox/s (and/or other control) to a temporary text file or database (kanown also as journaling) everytime the value of the textbox/s change or losing their focus.

And when your applications loads it check for its journal and loads the data.  If you were done with the data then clear it.